# Redirección de página y destrucción de sesión al pulsar un boton PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un botón que al pulsarlo debería de destruirme una sessión en php y redirigirme a una página que tengo que se encuentra en la misma carpeta a su misma altura. Pero no me funciona ni una cosa ni la otra.

Adjunto el cógido por si me podeis echar una mano.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
session_start();
include 'funtions.php';
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Gestion instituto</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST['enviar'])) {
            $nombre = $_REQUEST['nombre'];
            $clave = $_REQUEST['clave'];

            if (checkUser($arrayRoles, $nombre) == true) {
                $_SESSION["usuario_valido"] = $_REQUEST['nombre'];
            }
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION["usuario_valido"])) {
            print ("Buenas " . $_REQUEST['nombre']);
            print("<br>Menu<br>");
            print('<input type="submit" name="sesionDestroy" value="Cerrar sesion"/>');
            if (isset($_REQUEST["sesionDestroy"])) {
                session_destroy();
                header('Location: holaMundo.php');
            }
            /* print("<br><a href='alta.php'>Altas</a>");
              print("<br><a href='baja.php'>Bajas</a>");
              print("<br><a href='modificaciones.php'>Modificaciones</a>"); */
        } else if (isset($_REQUEST['nombre'])) {
            ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" size="20" /><br>
                Contraseña: <input type="password" name="clave">
                <br>
                <br><p><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" /><input type="submit" name="createUser" value="Crear usuario" /></p>
            </form>
            <h4>Acceso dengado fallo en la autenticacion</h4>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" size="20" /><br>
                Contraseña: <input type="password" name="clave">
                <br>
                <br><p><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" /><input type="submit" name="createUser" value="Crear usuario" /></p>
            </form>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

En el archivo `funtions.php` que incluyo en la página contiene un array con tres usuarios y un array que comprueba si lo introducido en el input se encuentra en el array. Devuelve true si coincide con algún valor del vector.

Comment: No veo que el botón esté dentro de un formulario.

Comment: 5 lineas mas arriba del cierre del body esta el boton

Comment: y el boton que quiero que desencadene el session destroy esta aqui https://imgur.com/a/8GA21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas mezclando lenguajes.

Para destruir la sesión crea un archivo aparte y haz que el boton te lleve a el.

destruir_sesion.php

```
<?php
/* Destruir la sesion */
session_start();
session_destroy();
/* Redirigir */
header('Location: holaMundo.php');
```

Y en el archivo que quieras pon el botón que te envie a `destruir_sesion.php`

```
<form action='destruir_sesion.php'>
    <input type="submit" name="sesionDestroy" value="Cerrar sesion"/>
</form>
```

---

También recuerda esta nota de [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php), tu código no cumple esto.

> **Nota:** Para usar sesiones basadas en cookies, session_start() debe ser llamada **antes de imprimir cualquier cosa en el navegador**.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda ;D. Pero mi duda que me ha surgido ahora es. El session start lo hice entre el la etiqueta <!DOCTYPE html> y la primera etiqueta <html>. Podrias especificarme en que lugar deberia de situarlo?

Comment: ¿Encima de la etiqueta <!DOCTYPE html>?

Comment: @Eduardo Si antes de que se imprima cualquier caracter.